# Get model values with adding specific items in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel as an API, but have some troubles with getting posts with the specific updated value.

Here is my code. Any help to fix the code regarding both syntax and inefficiencies?

```
use Controller;
use Post;
use User;
use Comment;

class HomeController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        $posts = $this->getPosts('home');

        return view('template', ['posts' = $posts]);
    }

    public function getPosts($slug){
        $posts = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();

        foreach($posts as &$post){
            $post->user = User::find($post->user_id);
            $post->comments = Comment::where('post_id', '=', $post->post_id)->get();

            foreach($post->comments as &$comment){
                $comment->user = User::find($comment->user_id);
            }
        }

        return $posts;
    }
}
```

Model

```
class Post extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'post';

    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'html', 'slug', 'user_id'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please include the Post model in your question.

Comment: Post model is fine, just issue with controller.

Comment: if it's a static function you should use it as `static::getPosts()`  instead of `$this->getPosts()`

Comment: thanks, i just updated, i'm not using static, but still an issue. seems there is a logic issue in foreach

Comment: It looks like something you could do more easily by defining the correct relationships in your models

Comment: a few things that feels off. First use Controller and models without namespaces, then getPosts should be done with relationships and method inside the model.

Comment: i added model in the question

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @WilliamWang I asked your post model as I wanted to see how did you define your relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the relationships in your Models, your `getPosts` function could be reduced to just

```
$posts = Post::with(['user', 'comments.user'])->where('slug', $slug)->get();
```

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'post_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::clsas, 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you please look through to my codebase that i have done in controller what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other people that it would be nice if you could use relationships instead. However for your question about your code, I think the problem lies at the code below.

```
        $post->comments = Comment::where('post_id', '=', $post->post_id)->get();
```

`$post->post_id` should be `$post->id` instead.